# Nested for loop in kotlin with a starts at in the inner loop

Tags: kotlin

I'm not immediately figuring out the syntax for this, but I want to do this java "correctly" in kotlin:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for(int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
    // do something here.
  }
}
```

The important bit being that the inner loop starts at whatever the current value of i is.

I can do something like this...

```
for((i, num1) in array.withIndex()) {
  for((j, num2) in array.withIndex()) {
    // do something here.
  }
}
```

but the problem is this will start at 0 instead of skipping ahead to i.  I could use a range and then access the array directly, but not sure if there is something cleaner in kotlin for this type of situation.  The best I can think of is...

```
for(i in 0..(array.size)) {
  for(j in i..array.size)) {
    // do something here, access array directly with indices.
  }
}
```

Is this the best I'm going to do in this context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ranges are the cleanest way to produce the equivalent of a Java `for(;;)` loop. Generally if the range is declared on the spot, the compiler even compiles it as a `for(;;)` so no Range object has to be instantiated.

But you need to use `until` instead of `..` because ranges are inclusive.

```
for (i in array.indices) {
    for (j in i until array.size) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Edit:
`until` is legacy, and now the preferred operator for a non-end-inclusive range is `..<`

```
for (i in array.indices) {
    for (j in i..<array.size) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this out and it is the result I wanted; can you explain what the use of indices is here?  Is it just for a consistent pattern [vs, maybe ((i, num) in array) for instance?)

Comment: It’s just concise. If you’re using the value of array[i], you could use what you have in your second box of code for the outer loop.