# Where i mistake? I can not get get for loop Value

Tags: kotlin, for-loop

I want to get "VacationCount" from my offday string. I have tried this code, but it does not work. Where is my mistake?

```
val offDaysString = "8888856"
val returnPending = 20 //How many day return Pending

var vacationCount = 0

if (offDaysString != null){
    val offDays: Array<String> = offDaysString.toCharArray().map {
        it.toString()
    }.toTypedArray() // Split all data from a string value

    for (i in 0 until  returnPending){
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE,i.toInt()) //Current Date, Which every loop add one day.
        val today = cal.timeInMillis/(1000*60*60*24*7) % 7 //Today Day like sun=0, Mon=1, Tue=2, wed=3
        for (j in 0 until offDays.size){
            if (offDays[j].toInt() == today.toInt()){ //Compayer All week to
               vacationCount++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try some for looping patterns but not work.
[Nested for loop in kotlin with a starts at in the inner loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423341/nested-for-loop-in-kotlin-with-a-starts-at-in-the-inner-loop)

Comment: Nothing looks particularly wrong with your code. I would find a way to display the value of `offDays` (after you first split it) or `offDays[j]` (in your inner loop) to make sure it contains what you expected. If that doesn't help, please edit your post to show us a sample of `offDaysString`, and explain what you expected to get and what you actually got.

Comment: Hello @NickGris, I have a specific date say "January 10, 2024, 12:30:00" I want to find the number of Fridays and Saturdays between that date and today.

For this, I have created a parenthesis using "8888856" as the offDaysString.

Comment: `cal.add(Calendar.DATE,i.toInt()) //Current Date, Which every loop add one day.` are you sure? did you verify that?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, cal.add(Calendar.DATE,i.toInt()) this work parfect. But the second loop does not work perfectly.

Comment: @JamineeRanjanMondal are you really sure? `cal.add` modifies the calendar, and `i` takes values of `0, 1, 2, 3, ... 19`, so you should be skipping a lot of days

Comment: @NickGris I have need January 10, 2024 to till now how many Saturday and Friday?can you recommend any fresh code?

Comment: @JamineeRanjanMondal: I think your inner loop is OK. Now that I understand what offDaysString is for, I have to agree with @njzk2 - assuming `cal` is Jan 10 (for example), the first loop sets it to (Jan 10 + 0) = Jan 10, the second loop sets it to (Jan 10 + 1) = Jan 11, the third loop sets it to (Jan 11 + 2) = Jan 13... you lost Jan 12. You would have to reset `cal` back to Jan 10 each time to get that right. But why use 'returnPending' anyway? If you want today, why not just use 'Calendar.getInstance()'?

Comment: @njzk2 thank you for your help. I find another issue also val today = cal.timeInMillis/(1000*60*60*24*7) % 7 does not work properly. have any suggestions? I have to need millisecond to week numbers like sun=0, mon=1,... 

My Debog Report:
i = 0 Thu Feb 22 14:55:43 GMT+06:00 2024 Today: 4
i = 1 Fri Feb 23 14:55:43 GMT+06:00 2024 Today: 4

Comment: @JamineeRanjanMondal: Can you not use cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)? The reason - I now realise - it doesn't work as you have coded it is because simply dividing the milliseconds assumes that at absolute 0 it was exactly the start of the week (day 0 of the week). It was day 0 of the year back then, but not likely day 0 of the week...

Comment: @NickGris Thanks for your help. All programs working well.